# Maven test-dependency removes transitive compile-dependency from uberjar

Tags: maven, dependency-management, spring-boot-maven-plugin

We have `splunk-library-javalogging` as compile-dependency and added `com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp` as a test-dependency. okhttp is also a compile-dependency of the splunk-appender.

Using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` we realized the okhttp-Dependency is no longer included, when added as a test-dependency. Removing it, it is included again.

So it seems scoping okhttp as test overrides the transitive compile-dependency (excluding it from the jar) - and this doesn't feel correct!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not feel correct, but it is unfortunately the case.

Maven determines the scopes first, then creates the classpaths. And direct dependencies override transitive ones.

It would be smarter to create the compile classpath by just ignoring `test` scoped dependency entries, but this is not how Maven does it.

Quintessence: Only add a test dependency if the dependency is not already in `mvn dependency:list`.